# Kivy: Add JSON Object inside another JSON Object using kivy.storage.jsonstore

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, kivy, jsonstore

I'm New on kivy. I want to save my settings of KivyApplication in a JSON file.

I want to create a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "user_name": "person_1",
      "password": "1234"
    },
    {
      "user_name": "person_2",
      "password": "5678"
    }
  ]
}
```

I found an example in Kivy API references web page ([Kivy JSON Storage Example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage)).

Here is my solution for add multiple JSON Objects to the Main JSON Object:

### JsonStore.py:

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('hello.json')

users_list = [{"user_name": "person_1", "password": "1234"},
              {"user_name": "person_2", "password": "5678"}]
# put some values
for u in users_list:
    print(u)
    store.put('users', u)
```

But this error occur:

```
store.put('users', u)
TypeError: put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here and how to make this work? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is kind of predefined by `put(object_name, attribute1=value1[, attribute2=value2, ...])`.

To accomplish what you want, you have to give `users` a key to hold your list of objects.

Long story short, this code should work:

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('hello.json')

users_list = [{"user_name": "person_1", "password": "1234"},
          {"user_name": "person_2", "password": "5678"}]

store.put('users', objects=users_list)
```